# why won't my jquery dialog fully fadeOut()?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

When I call fadeOut on my dialog it only does a partial fade and leaves the grey header area where the dialog title is. I've tried removing the title as well as the various attributes that disable the exit button in the upper right corner of the dialog, but that didn't work. As you'll see in my script below, I want the dialog to close after the form submission has been validated.

```
//HTML
 <div id="dialog"> 
     <form id="form">

         <p id="thanks">Please provide a contact number. It will only be shared with the 
host</p><input id="number" name="number" type="text"/>

    <button id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>

 </form>

 </div>

//JS
 if(myConditional){

            //FORM IS HIDDEN ON PAGE LOAD AND SHOWN ON CLICK  

            $('form').show();

            $('#dialog').dialog({

//These parameters are meant to disable the dialog close button

    closeOnEscape: false,
   beforeclose: function (event, ui) { return false; },
   dialogClass: "noclose",
   title: "Thanks For Volunteeering",
   minWidth: 500

});
            $('button').button();

        }else{
           //other code
        }

 //Validate the phone number before saving it to local storage   

     $("#form").validate({
            rules: {
                  number : {
                    required: true
                    customvalidation: true
                }                                        
            },
            messages: {
                number : {
                    required: "enter a phone number"                   
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {

                   var number = $('#number').val();

localStorage.setItem('number', JSON.stringify(number));



                    //THIS FADE OUT ISN'T FULLY FADING THE DIALOG

                     $('#dialog').fadeOut();

            }  //closes submit handler  
        });//close validate
```

Comment: try removing `     $('form').show();`

Comment: I tried it and still have the problem.

Comment: Are there any errors in console ?

Comment: There aren't any relevant errors in the apache console, no.

Comment: I meant javascript console. Anyways, your error seems solved now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. 
I got rid of the *beforeClose* parameter in the dialog init code, and in the form validation submit handler I added this:

```
 $('#dialog').fadeOut('slow', function(){
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );

                    });

//The fadeOut method has a call back function you can use with it to do something after the fade is completed.
```